# mysql cli; password works when prompted, but not when passes as command argument

Tags: mysql

Can’t figure this out, and all of my searching hasn’t helped.

When I login to mysql and I enter

```
$ mysql -u database_user -p
Enter password:  ******* #here I enter my_password
```

this works.  the next thing I see is the `mysql>` command prompt.  However, if I enter

```
$ mysql -u database_user -pmy_password
```

or

```
$ mysql -u database_user --password=my_password
```

Both of which, according to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html), should be allow me access.  I get the access denied response.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'database_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I've tried a lot of variations specifying database or host:

```
$ mysql -u database_user -pmy_password -d database_xxx -h localhost
```

But I keep getting the Access Denied error.

I want to pass my password as a command line argument so I can write some scripts to automate some tasks.

Has anyone else run into this issue or know why if I'm prompted for a password, I'm good, but if I pass it in as an argument, I cannot login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your password doesn't happen to have a '$' in it, like `pa$$word`?  Or another character that might mean something to the shell?

In that case you will need to enclose your password with single quotes `'`

```
$ mysql -u database_user -p'my_password'
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure exactly why you are having that problem, I strongly recommend against passing the password on the command line. The best practice is put the password in a secure file and use the [`--defaults-extra-file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_defaults-extra-file) option. That way the password is not displayed in plaintext in the process table.

For your example, you could create a `/etc/mysql_login.cnf` file and permission it such that only you can read it, then put this in the file:

```
[client]
user=database_user
password=my_password
```

Then call the mysql cli like this:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysql_login.cnf
```

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment, as it is **not answering the question** of why the command-line password isn't working (admittedly risky, but nonetheless supported).

Comment: I disagree. The OP's goal is to "write some scripts to automate some tasks", and the initial method did not work, so I'm offering a method that should work.